# Programmatically instantiating a mailto

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, mailto

I have a website with a "place order" button, and above it is a list of products and textboxes allowing me to set a quantity for each product.

On the click of the button it posts back and calculated how many of each product is required, I then put this into a big string with "mailto:order@blah.com" at the front. I now want to somehow get that to pop up into the client automatically at the end of the postback.

I've tried window.open but this also opens a new browser window which I want to avoid.

Button postback code:

```
protected void btnPlaceOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url = "mailto:orders@blah.com?subject=New order from " + ddlSelectLocation.SelectedItem.Value;
            url += "&body=Please raise a new order for the following items:" + Environment.NewLine;
            foreach (GridViewRow row in grdOrder.Rows)
            {
                string model = row.Cells[0].Text;
                int qty = 0;
                TextBox txt = (TextBox)row.Cells[3].Controls[1];
                if (int.TryParse(txt.Text, out qty))
                {
                    if (qty > 0)
                        url += " - " + model + ": " + qty.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                }
            }
            url += Environment.NewLine + "Many Thanks.";

            Response.Write(url);
        }
```

Otherwise I'm going to have to write a load of clientside javascript code :(

Comment: use document.window instead of window.open

Comment: Will that remove the contents of my current window view though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try something like this?

```
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
        "MAIL",
        "window.open('" + url + "')",
        true);
```

You'll have to make sure the string is properly escaped...

Comment: "I've tried window.open but this also opens a new browser window which I want to avoid" - am I passing the wrong parameters then?

Comment: Not sure... I wired this up on my side, and after the postback I immediately got my email client opening up... (after the browser confirmation box). It must be a personalised setting within the browser perhaps?

Comment: The only other thing that you can possibly try is to navigate a hidden iframe to the mailto: address. but I'm not sure what that will do. It's worth a try?

Comment: Come to think of it... even your code as is with the response.write opened up my mail client straight away... must be a browser setting.

Comment: Having done some fiddling it looks like it may have been the content of the mailto body that was causing the issue.  Thanks for your help!